# List of Dataframes, drop Dataframe column (columns have different names) if row contains a special string

Tags: python, pandas

What i have is a list of Dataframes.

What is important to note is that the shape of the dataframes differ between 2-7 columns, also the columns are named between 0 & len of the column (e.g. df1 has 5 columns named 0,1,2,3,4 etc. df2 has 4 columns named 0,1,2,3)

I would like is to check if a row in a column contains a certain string, then delete that column.

```
list_dfs1=[df1,df2,df3...df100]
```

What i have done so far is the below & i get an error that column 5 is not in axis (it is there for some DF)

```
for i, df in enumerate(list_dfs1):
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        if np.where(row.str.contains("DEC")):
            df.drop(index, axis=1)
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
for df in list_dfs:
    for col in df.columns:
        # If you are unsure about column types, cast column as string:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
        # Check if the column contains the string of interest
        if df[col].str.contains("DEC").any():
            df.drop(columns=[col], inplace=True)
```

If you know that all columns are of type string, you don't have to actually do `df[col] = df[col].astype(str)`.

Comment: I meant a row in a column contains a certain string, not the column name itself.

Comment: That is precisely what the code does. If at least one row in the column contains "DEC", then drop that entire column. `df[col]` returns the entire column as a ´Series´ object, and `.str.contains("DEC").any()` checks if any value in this series contains "DEC".

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function that checks whether the dataframe has the pattern or not. You can use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`pd.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html)

```
def func(s):
    return s.str.contains('DEC').any()

list_df = [df.loc[:, ~df.apply(func)] for df in list_dfs1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take another approach. I would concatenate the list into a data frame and then eliminate the column where finding the string

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat(list_dfs1)
```

Let us say your condition was to eliminate any column with `"DEC"`

```py
df.mask(df == "DEC").dropna(axis=1, how="any")
```